# Do nav bars require a title to appear?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm a beginner trying to learn Swift with hackingwithswift.com. One of the first tasks is to add a nav bar to my app, but I'm facing a bit of trouble understanding how nav bars work. I can code a nav bar with a title in just fine, but I can't seem to create one without adding the modifier `.navigationTitle()` even though the video seems to be able to do so.

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Nav bar") // doesn't seem to work without this
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried removing the content within `.navigationTitle()` or removing the modifier entirely but neither seem work.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/adding-a-navigation-bar)? That is written in 2021. The behaviour is probably different now in iOS 17.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, that's the one. I figured that the website would be a little outdated but most people on Reddit recommended using it to learn Swift. Do you know how I could either (a) figure out on my own what is outdated or (b) find a more up-to-date place to learn?

Comment: @Timothy always keep looking at the official docs by Apple, whenever a new iOS version is released it comes with a list of API's that have been deprecated.

Comment: you could try using `.navigationBarHidden(false)` to show an empty navigationBar
 without having to use a `navigationTitle(...)`. Seems to do what it says. Note,
 `NavigationView` is deprecated use `NavigationStack` instead.